# Excel way to add serie in hard with skipped values

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I use some series in Excel with "hard coded" values, hear "without using reference the cells address".

I do this by adding this kind of formula in the Excel chart :

```
"=SERIES(""My serie"",{""A"",""B"",""C"",""D""},{5,10,15,12},1)"
```

Now if I want to skip values lets say to start the serie from B in this example, how should I write it with this notation ?

Said otherly, I want the same behavior of the chart when there is no value in the cell : the value is not plotted.

I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
"=SERIES(""My serie"",{""A"",""B"",""C"",""D""},{,10,15,12},1)"
```

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

=SERIES("My series",{5, #N/A, 10, 15, 12},1)

This tells Excel to plot the points 5, 10, 15, and 12, but to skip the second point by using #N/A. The chart will automatically skip the points with #N/A values, and the line will not be plotted for those points.

Comment: it works dude ! Thanks!!